# p-smooth numbers that are adjacent on the Stern-Brocot tree

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

An interesting question from looking at the Stern-Brocot tree:

Two rational numbers, call them $a/b$ and $c/d$, are "adjacent" on the Stern-Brocot tree if and only if we have $ad-bc = \pm 1$, meaning that one will be parent to the other. (I think this also means that the continued fraction expansion of one is an initial segment of the other, except perhaps for the very last digit of that initial segment.)

Now suppose that we look at the set of all strictly positive rationals whose numerator and denominator are both $p$-smooth integers for some prime $p$. There will be infinitely many such rationals. **Are there infinitely many "adjacent" $p$-smooth pairs if $p>2$?** If not, how many are there and is there some way to compute them?

Better yet, suppose that we instead look at some other arbitrary finitely-generated subgroup of $\langle \Bbb Q^+, \cdot \rangle$, the multiplicative group of strictly positive rationals. This generalizes the situation with $p$-smooth numbers above. **For which subgroups are there guaranteed to be infinitely many "adjacent" pairs?**

Comment: It's difficult for smooth numbers to differ by $1$ like that; maybe applying the abc conjecture will get you somewhere.

Comment: Ah, of course! OK, so if $ad-bc = 1$, then $ad/bc$ is a $p$-smooth superparticular ratio, and we know there are only finitely many of those for any $p$. Thanks!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: OK, so the answer is simple - clearly for any group of only $p$-smooth rationals, there are only finitely many such of these "adjacent" rationals due to Størmer's theorem. And since *any*  finitely-generated multiplicative group of positive rationals embeds into some $p-$smooth group, for which there are only finitely many, we know there are also only finitely many for every possible subgroup of rationals. I'm not sure how the abc conjecture relates but I think this answers my question; if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it otherwise I'll write it myself later...